# Phonegap - Detecting network activity

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova

### Scenario

I have made a phonegap 1.0.0 app which loads the current location via Google Map. I have also created a plugin to display the activity indicator on the top of the screen, i.e. on the status bar of the iPhone.

```
function onBodyLoad()
{   
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
};

function onDeviceReady()
{
    //Get the plugin object
    var ai = window.plugins.ActivityIndicator;
    //Stop the spin, if any activity was going on earlier
    ai.end();
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        //Start spinning, indicating that some network activity is going on
        ai.set();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initSearch);
    }
    else alert("Please try reloading");
    //Stop spinning after 10 seconds
    window.setTimeout(ai.end, 10000);
};
```

The Javascript code for the plugin is as follows:

```
var ActivityIndicator = function() {};
ActivityIndicator.prototype.set = function() 
{
    PhoneGap.exec("ActivityIndicator.start");
};
ActivityIndicator.prototype.end = function() 
{
    PhoneGap.exec("ActivityIndicator.end");
};
ActivityIndicator.install = function() {
    if(!window.plugins)
        window.plugins = {};
    window.plugins.ActivityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator();
    return window.plugins.ActivityIndicator;
};
PhoneGap.addConstructor(ActivityIndicator.install);
```

The Objective-C code for the plugin is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
#import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
#else
#import "PGPlugin.h"
#endif

@interface ActivityIndicator : PGPlugin {}
-(void) start:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
-(void) end:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
@end

@implementation ActivityIndicator

- (void)start:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
}

- (void)end:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}

@end
```

### Problem

As you can see in the code snippet above, I have set the Timeout for the spinning to stop after 10 seconds.

### Question

How to make the activityIndicator start/stop whenever there is any network Activity?

Comment: For the map loading scenario alone, I used Google map api events tilesloaded and center_changed to solve my problem. Hopefully someone can answer this and solve a generic problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could've use [notificationEx](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NotificationEx) instead of doing your own, but it's good for knowledge :)

Anyways, is the map calls ajax-based? If yes, and you are using jQuery, assign `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` functs.

I do the following:

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
    /* ===============
    // Bind Ajax calls with
    // activity Indicator
    // =============== */
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        navigator.notificationEx.activityStart();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        navigator.notificationEx.activityStop();
    });
//other stuff
}
```

This way, all ajax will be shown in the activity when happening.

Update:
For [Zeptojs](http://zeptojs.com) - on version 0.8 or superior [ajax global implemented only on v0.8](https://gist.github.com/1337487), use the following:

```js
function onDeviceReady() {
    /* ===============
    // Bind Ajax calls with
    // activity Indicator - ZEPTO
    // =============== */
    $(document).on('ajaxStart',function() {
        navigator.notificationEx.activityStart();
    }).on('ajaxStop',function() {
        navigator.notificationEx.activityStop();
    });
//other stuff
}
```

Comment: Awesome man! I will try this. By the way, I use zepto for my project. Will this function work? Or should I use jQuery?